# Ansible ec2_eni module. How to add additional security_groups for an ec2_eni interface?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying add additional security_groups to my existing ec2_ENIs. The module ec2_eni seems like non idempotent. When I add a new security group using ec2_eni module it removes the existing groups and adds only the group I have mentioned in the playbook.

So the option left for me is to get the existing ec2_eni_facts and upate it as a fact. Problem with this approach is the values are coming in nested arrays like below example. How to get the security groups alone as a fact?

Ansible version 2.5.1

```
Playbook:
---
- hosts: ansiblecontroller
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  user: root

  tasks:
    - ec2_eni_facts:
        filters:
          network-interface-id: "eni-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      register: enifacts
    - debug: msg="{{ enifacts }}"

    - name: set empty list
      set_fact:
        name1: "ENI1"
        grouplist: []
        fact1: []
        parthas: []
        security_groups: []
    - name: set empty list
      set_fact:
        fact1: "{{ enifacts | json_query('network_interfaces[*].groups[*]') }}"
        grouplist: "{{ grouplist }} + [ '{{ name1 }}' ]"

    - debug: msg="{{ grouplist }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ fact1 }}"



Result:
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.21.10.155] => {
    "msg": "[u'ENI1'] + [ '[[{u'group_id': u'sg-0bf33819021de5d15', u'group_name': u'default'}, {u'group_id': u'sg-008569a91671d5090', u'group_name': u'Lab4-INTRA-VPC-Subnet-Traffic'}]]' ]"
}

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.21.10.155] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "group_id": "sg-0bf33819021de5d15",
                "group_name": "default"
            },
            {
                "group_id": "sg-008569a91671d5090",
                "group_name": "Lab4-INTRA-VPC-Subnet-Traffic"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this not work for you if you provide it with parameters associated with your EIP?
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/ec2_group_facts_module.html#ec2-group-facts-module